# MSBuild Missing from TFS 2015 Build Templates

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I have upgraded to TFS 2015 Update 3 and can't find MSBuild in the available build templates. Only the following ones are available:

Any help to getting MSBuild installed would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's what happen when you have a printed book that's only a year out of date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am on TFS 2015 update 2 and I don't see any `MSBuild` Build Templates available to me either. However, I would just use the `MSBuild` task after selecting the empty Build Template at the bottom of the picture you provided. I don't think a `MSBuild` Build Template exists for TFS 2015.
[image: MSBuild Task]

Also, whether or not `MSBuild` is installed is based on the Agent running your builds, not based on the build templates. You can see if your Agent can use `MSBuild` by viewing its capabilities under your agent pools at {tfs-name}:8080/tfs/_admin/_AgentPool
[image: Agent Capabilities]

Answer (score 1):

There's never been an MSBuild template. There has been, and still is, however, an MSBuild task. You can use the MSBuild task in any build definition.